# what am i doing wrong in this code? im trying to check if all the elements in a list are the same, and no matter the test cases i get a #f

Tags: recursion, scheme

Create the function AllEqual?(L) which will be given a list of (at least 2) elements and will return #t if all of them are the same, otherwise #f

```
(define (allequal? l)
  (if (< (length l) 2) 
      #t
      (equal? (car l) (allequal? (cdr l)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(equal? (car l) (allequal? (cdr l)))
```

tests if `(car l)` is `equal?` to `(allequal? ...)`. Since `allequal?` returns a boolean (`#t` or `#f`), you test if `(car l)` is `#t` or `#f`, which is not what you want.

You need to compare the first two elements, if available, and then recurse on the `cdr` of your list:

```
(define (allequal? l)
  (if (< (length l) 2)
      #t 
      (and (equal? (car l) (cadr l))
           (allequal? (cdr l)))))
```

or, easier,

```
(define (allequal? l)
  (or (< (length l) 2)
      (and (equal? (car l) (cadr l))
           (allequal? (cdr l)))))
```

or even

```
(define (allequal? l)
  (or (null? l)
      (null? (cdr l))
      (and (equal? (car l) (cadr l))
           (allequal? (cdr l)))))
```

Comment: ahhhh now i see what i did wrong, thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @William if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.